# Error while executing npm install -g botium-cli

Tags: git, npm, chatbot

Getting error

> npm ERR! Error while executing: npm ERR! C:\Program
>   Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t
>   https://github.com/codeforequity-at/jsonpath.git

while installing botium -cli with npm

but while running

> git ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/codeforequity-at/jsonpath.git

separately it is running fine without any error

Comment: Is there more error information available ?

Comment: Thanks @FlorianTreml This issue got resolved after updating git to latest version .Earlier I was using 2.13 now I updated to 2.20